# How to pull value from array in Mongo deep nested documents

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure in MongoDB 2.6:

```
db.processes: {
    _id: ObjectId("572756344031b585d03dca57"),

    activities: [
      { 
        procedures: [
          {
            implications_ids: [ 
              ObjectId("50871f11d52ef600020128a2"), ObjectId("50871f17d52ef60002012d03")
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to remove the value `ObjectId("50871f11d52ef600020128a2")` from all arrays `implications_ids`. I wrote the command:

```
`db.processes.update({},
 { $pull: { activities: { procedures: { implications_ids: ObjectId("50871f11d52ef600020128a2") } } } },
 { multi: true, safe: true }
)`
```

The command finishes execution, but does not update any documents:

`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 199, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this one. I tested in mongo3.2, so not sure if this works as well in 2.6

```
  db.foo.update({}, { $pull: { "activities.procedures.implications_ids"  : ObjectId("50871f11d52ef600020128a2") }},  { multi: true } )
```

I use

```
db.foo.insert( { activities: {
      procedures: {
        implications_ids: [ ObjectId("50871f11d52ef600020128a2"),
                          ObjectId("50871f17d52ef60002012d03")]
      }
    }
  });
```

And get

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

> db.foo.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5723a45f0a8d4f8f305690e6"), "activities" : { "procedures" :
{ "implications_ids" : [ ObjectId("50871f17d52ef60002012d03") ] } } }
>
```

After command execution, just change the name of your document

Comment: Interesting, when I tried the update with dot notation as you proposed I got the message: 'cannot use the part (activities of activities.procedures.implications_ids) to traverse the element ({activities: [ {_id: ObjectId(), ... }]

Comment: Past your insert statement and I could check

Comment: The insert statement that correctly reflects my db structure is: 

db.processes.insert(
  { activities: [
    { procedures: [ 
        { implications_ids: [ ObjectId("50871f11d52ef600020128a2"), ObjectId("50871f17d52ef60002012d03")] }
    ]}
  ]}
)